# Are there any UX Patterns or research that support Mac OS treating standard dropdowns (selects) as modal like interaction?

Tags: user-behavior, user-research, dropdown

**Background:**

Recently I was working with a widget ([Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)), and found what I felt was a rather large UX issue, the `<select>` box (dropdown) was being treated as modal interaction with a transparent mask blocking interaction to the webpage below.  The creators defense was this is standard interaction in Mac OS (and also solved several technical problems for him as well).

**Question:**

My question to this community is what patterns or UX research defends Apples decision to make standard select boxes a modal interaction?  To be specific, it blocks interaction with the application until a selection is made or the user closes the dropdown by clicking outside the dropdown.  To me this flew in the face of the expected users mental model, and seems to diminish usability, though this is simply my opinion and I open it up to you guys to better defend or argue against.

**Additional Info**

As of right now I know this happens in at least Mac OS 10.9.  If you have that version installed you can try this by going to [W3Schools select box](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select).  which is a vanilla select.  Click on the select, and try to interact with anything else, such as browser tabs, switching to a different app in the background (by clicking on it), or even click on the main OS bar at the top.  You should notice that your click is ignored and instead only closes the select dropdown.

Comment: Following the link, I don't see the widget exhibiting this behavior. Am I missing something? Also, I prefer to avoid modals wherever possible.

Comment: @MattLavoie You must use one of the customized dropdowns (In the first example it shows a standard select, and then what it turns into)  Click on the second dropdown and then scroll up (if needed) and hover over one of the buttons or links.  You should notice it does not trigger any hover effects making them appear disabled.  Now click on one of them.  Nothing happens, reinforcing that they are disabled.  However, now notice after you clicked the hover effect is triggered, click a second time to use the button.

Comment: Hmm, I dont know that I would necessarily consider that a modal. It doesn't prevent the user from cognitively processing any of the rest of the content on the page. Really all it does is inflict a click to close before I can click on something else, but without the gray overlay it doesn't mentally prevent me from jumping to something else. hmm.

Comment: I'm not sure OSX *does* create modals from drop down lists. Can you cite the source of this information?

Comment: @MattLavoie  Modal as I am using it is refering to the interface entering into a mode where the user must interact with the current item before interacting with the main application.  In this case the select-box does not allow the user to interact with any other element until it is closed.  Such as with the definition of a modal window: "...a child window that requires users to interact with it before they can return to operating the parent application, thus preventing the workflow on the application main window" (from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) a gray overlay is not needed.

Comment: @DA01 I confirmed this on Mac OS (latest version) itself in both chrome, and safari.  I have searched and can't find any mention of discussion on them changing this, but if you have an up to date machine you can see it for yourself.  This happens on vanilla select-boxes (I ensured that by using a W3C schools example).  I am unsure which version of Mac OS first introduced this.  I have to admit I use a Mac at home (PC at work) and had not noticed the change, though I only recently upgraded the OS.

Comment: @ChrisJanssen I'm on 10.8.5 and any select box I can find in the native UI is just a plain'ol select box. I can select it, but I'm also free to select anything else on the screen. I'm not stuck in any sort of modal. Can you perhaps post some screen shots of what you are seeing?

Comment: @DA01 I am on Mac OS 10.9, if you go to |     http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select     | and simply open the select box, now try to do anything else before making a selection or closing the select box.  For instance try to change tabs.  Notice nothing happens on first click.  Try changing apps by clicking one in the background, ignored.  Hover over your bookmark bar, notice no hover effect.  These are all objects outside of the browser, yet apple makes the interaction modal while the dropdown is open.  If it doesn't happen for you then 10.9 may be the first version.

Comment: @DA01 As for screenshots, as they use a transparent mask, there isnt much to show.  And I dont have anything to take a timed screenshot to show the lack of hover effects. The user is not really informed they are in a modal mode other than any click other than to select an option in the dropdown is ignored and only closes the dropdown.  As with the definition of modal window above, this to me fits with my definition of modal.  I can not use the main application (or any other) until the current interface (or window as the dropdown menu is technically a window) has been used or dismissed.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the detailed description. Yes, I see it now too. However, I don't see it with native OSX ui elements. This only appears to affect web browsers. Webkit browsers appear to 'mute' all interactions while the menu is open. Firefox still shows hovers and such, but you do still need to do the 'double-click' thing. I really have no idea what the thinking was behind this, or if this is even an OSX thing (maybe it's a browser thing?). My best (but wild) guess is that this is an accessibility enhancement.

Comment: Also, I can see where the terminology confusion is coming from. I agree that it has somewhat of a 'modal' interaction. But I don't think most people would see it as an actual modal. Note that actual modals in OSX browsers are quite different (the entire page darkens, for example). Also, an actual modal tends to require that you act with the modal before you can do anything else. This example is rather unique in that you can dismiss the modal by (attempting to) interact with something elsewhere on the screen. Still, it's an interesting question!

Comment: @DA01 Happy to alter phrasing, but I am refering to a modal interaction rather than specifically a modal window which I believe you are comparing it to.  I would point out the not all modal windows require action within the window itself to dismiss it.  For instance many photo galleries are designed to dismiss the modal by clicking outside of the photo window itself. Things in Mac OS such as the disclosure panels that would slide down from the top of a page, do not darken the screen, but are still modal windows.  Modal vs non-modal really hinges on if it blocks interaction with the application

Comment: I don't know that you have to re-word. I'd maybe say "Modal-like interaction" to be a bit more specific, but that's just me. It is a rather unique thing. For the record, the definition of a modal window is that you *do* have to interact with the window to dismiss: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window It's all fuzzy terms, of course, but one could argue that if you don't have to interact with the window to dismiss it, then it's not a true modal. (People may call it an overlay, or pop-up pane, or any other number of terms...many of them vague enough to be debatable)

Comment: (in the end, there's enough subjectivity in these terms we use in UX that that there's always room for debate)

Comment: @DA01 Good feedback, I have adjusted some of the wording as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

> My question to this community is what patterns or UX research defends
>   Apples decision to make standard select boxes a modal interaction?

Since you can click outside of the select box to close it, there's a danger that you could click on something destructive: what if you accidentally clicked a <kbd>Delete</kbd> button on the page below? To prevent this, the select box behaves like a modal so that any click outside of it simply closes the box – much safer.

Apple uses this elsewhere in OS X, too. For example, if you have a Mail window open in the background, clicks on destructive buttons (like Delete or Mark as Junk) are ignored so that you don't accidentally delete a message when clicking the window to bring it to the front.

Comment: Certainly preventing miss-clicks for destructive actions is a consideration but this is why destructive actions generally must be confirmed or can be undone.  I think if this is the only reason they did this, it is throwing out usability and changing the mental model of the user for a corner case.  It assumes the user isnt looking where they click, and they happen to click on an undesirable undo-able action.  Switching windows probably has a higher case of this, but preventing click-through when switching application windows should be dealt with on its own, not only in this case.

Comment: Well, in the browser, there isn't necessarily a confirmation or undo feature for each destructive action, since it depends entirely on the specific site/page – so it's much safer for an open select box to simply block _any_ click outside of it. In the case of a desktop app like Mail, preventing click-through on destructive buttons avoids the need for a confirmation dialog, which would be very annoying the rest of the time. And undo doesn't necessarily help since you might not realize you accidentally clicked a destructive button while bringing the window forward.

Comment: @ChrisJanssen What is the alternative though? Leaving the select open until a choice is explicitly clicked? What if it has 50+ options like a state select and covers up important parts of the page? What if checking a box elsewhere in the form changes the contents of the select? What if the user changes their mind and doesn't want to make a selection? It's better if they can click anywhere to dismiss it instead of having to find click a specific item in the list to put it back with no changes.

Comment: @NathanRabe  I think you misunderstand, the expectation is that clicking outside of a select indeed closes it.  The issue is that in OS X all other actions (hover, etc.) are suppressed with no modal underlay to indicate.  This to me is confusing to a users (previous) mental model, with no visual indication that the choice is modal.  Per the interaction in OS X the user would not be able to check a box elsewhere to affect the select (though I question that interaction anyway).  But yes clicking anywhere other than the dropdown should close it, the question is simply do you treat it as modal or

Comment: @ChrisJanssen Not every mode requires a modal dialog. There are lots of interface elements that cause software to briefly enter a different mode, but because the duration is expected to be short, no overlay or separate dialog is used. Selects, menu bars, right-clicking a dock icon, the classic Start Menu, etc. all briefly enter a mode without overt indicators. If anything, selects are more consistent with mental models of "You must make a choice from the list before doing anything else." Modal dialogs that dim the screen are generally the exception.

Comment: Nathan, yes everything shouldn't be modal. The question above was why did Apple chose to take a previously non-modal action and turn it modal.  (Secondary is their choice not to give any visual indication it was).  I'll also note that at least some of your examples aren't modals.  e.g. Windows Start Menu, Selects (outside of OSX), etc. Actions click through and are not canceled/prevented as would happen in a modal that closes when you click in the "gray" area.

Comment: @ChrisJanssen, mental models can differ from person to person and can adapt to systems. As a OS X user I can say that this "modal" behavior makes a lot of sense. What annoys me on Windows is that you have to click the window you want to scroll, but it annoys me more that the click actually triggers an action in it. I've also seen people that are only used to Windows making "mistakes" because of this. Preventing them from unwanted clicks is better than letting them undo their actions.

Comment: @jazZRo,  I think the discussion of should clicks into the inactive window/application click-through is a different discussion, as user expectations may be different, and it is easier to ignore mentally what you are clicking on, because you are just trying to bring the window to focus so you can do something else.  The question above focuses mainly on the interaction with the active application, with lack of visual feedback.  It does cover that on Mac OS all clicks are ignored, including clicks to change window focus, but that is less the point and can still be separated from click-through.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I've tested fiddling with dropdowns on a mac osx 10.9.1 and they work just like you would expect.
If you click in the combo and then click anywhere else, the combo closes with the option you had previously selected.

Dropdowns require lots of precision to select the option you want. This is crucial when you are working on a device makes it difficult to input data such as smartphones and tablets.
So for these scenarios, turning the dropdown into a modal interaction has benefits, like:

- You make sure the user is focused on making a choice
- You can make the choices bigger so that a choice is not made on accident
- If the user touches a dropdown (which can make a choice) the user will quickly realize that a choice is being made, and can revert it.

Now, modal interactions always introduce a burden since the user is surprised at first, which can be reduced if you keep the user in the same context for example by dimming the backgroud but leaving it visible so the user can understand where she is.
For devices where you have lots of input precision, like desktops where you use a mouse it probably does not make much sense to turn a dropdown into a modal window.

Comment: Yes, I get the point on Mobile Devices, there is limited space, the way you provide input is different, etc. However none of this supports why you would do this on a desktop browser when none of these concerns apply. (as you note in the end of your answer).